# psexec failing with return code 122 when used from Windows service

Tags: wcf, psexec

I've written a WCF service as a wrapper around a C# utility we've written that uses the SysInternals `psexec` utility to run jobs on a remote system. `psexec` is invoked from C# with command-line parameters that specify the domain, user and password to use.

All works fine when I invoke the C# utility from PowerShell locally.

However, when I run the utility from the WCF service we see a return code of 122, which corresponds to (?) "The data area passed to a system call is too small".

`psexec` is running against Windows Server 2008. The credentials I'm passing are local administrator, in the same domain as the machine that hosts the service wrapping the utility.

Comment: What account is your WCF service running under?

Comment: A regular domain user - not an admin. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Well, have you given it a try with SYSTEM?

Comment: Indeed; turns out that this was an old version of PSExec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this was most likely a bug fixed with PSExec version 1.97. This version appears to work just fine in this circumstance.